# primefaces wizard tabs update data tables

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, tabs, wizard

I have a page with a prime faces wizard that has 3 tabs, in my third tab there are two data tables, the first one is a list of data from a database and I have an Ajax on it that when I double click on a row it call a method to add the selected record to a different table in the same database and it gets inserted successfully and I can see it in the database table, but I want to get viewed in the second data table in my page as soon as it gets added (the second data table lists the data from my database) I have tried all the mentioned ideas on Ajax update but non of them worked for me!! can someone see what am I doing worng?

Here is my Wizard:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/layouts/exam_createor.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="frmSemesterExam">
            <p:wizard id="tabsSemesterExamId" widgetVar="wiz"
                flowListener="#{mbCoursesExamBank.onFlowProcess}" showNavBar="false"
                showStepStatus="true">
                <p:tab title="#{msg2.get('semester_exam')}" id="tabExamId">
                    <ui:include src="/pages/instructors/semester_course_exam.xhtml" />
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="#{msg2.get('forms')}" id="tabFormsId">
                    <ui:include src="/pages/instructors/exam_forms.xhtml" />
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="#{msg2.get('questions_in_this_form')}" id="tabQuestionsForm">
                    <ui:include src="/pages/instructors/questions_form.xhtml" />
                </p:tab>
            </p:wizard>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

And here is my third tab which has the dataTables:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">
<p:panelGrid columns="6" id="pnlfourmData1">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <div align="center">#{msg2.get('exam_forms')}</div>
    </f:facet>
</p:panelGrid>

<p:dataTable id="tblAllQuestions" value="#{mbInstructor.fullList}"
    var="asEmp" selectionMode="single"
    selection="#{mbInstructor.currentExamQuestion}" rowKey="#{asEmp.id}"
    rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
    <p:ajax event="rowDblselect"
        update="@parent:tblAllQuestions,frmSemesterExam:tabQuestionsForm"
        process="@this" listener="#{mbInstructor.submitForm()}" />
    <p:column headerText="#" width="8%">
                        #{rowIndex+1}
                    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{msg2.get('Questions')}">
                        #{asEmp.questionTxt}
                    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>



<p:dataTable id="tblAllQuestions2" value="#{mbInstructor.formsQuestion}"
    var="as" selectionMode="single"
    selection="#{mbInstructor.currentExamQuestion}" rowKey="#{as.id}"
    rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
    <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" update="@this" process="@this" />
    <p:column headerText="#" width="8%">
                        #{rowIndex+1}
                    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{msg2.get('Question in this form')}">
                        #{as.question.questionTxt}
                    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

</html>
```

Please note that I have tried to put my dataTables inside a form and update them but did not help!

Comment: First upon inserting, are you updating the `mbInstructor.formsQuestion` list? and why dont you use primefaces' PickList?: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml

Comment: Yes I'm updating the list after the insert. I have tried the pickList but the thing is I have two different types of list one of type Question and the Other of type ExamFormQuestions so I thought its impossible to do or at least I suffered to get it work and couldn't

Comment: and you sure the new value is on the list?

Comment: yes I am sure its in the list after the insert

Comment: Ok and why are you not updating the "tblAllQuestions2" table?

Comment: I have tried to update it in the ajax update and in my managed bean like this : RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("tblAllQuestions2"); but both did not work

Comment: @ouerghiYassine Any suggestions?

Comment: Well I would make sure to update the "tblAllQuestions2" from the p:ajax, and double check the "formsQuestion" list, is it getting updated with the newly added item or not.